# DisplayFormula font is hard to read in print

Tags: fonts, printing

My equations that use DisplayFormula style are a bit hard to read when printed on paper. Some lines look very thin. For example, a negative signs are so thin it is easy to miss them. Is there a way to make the formula font more prominent?

I am using the Default stylesheet. I am printing with Bother [HL-L2380DW laser printer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HRG01A4).

Here is my mathematica file: 
[assignment_for_stackexchange.nb](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8UknowN9xmxQU4tTmFNZ0ZuMms).

Here is a scan of a document from Mathematica:

[image]

Mathematica Version: 11.0.1

macOS Sierra

### Update

I managed to make the formulas readable in print by changing their text color to black (Format > Text Color menu).

Comment: I can't help on the typesetting in Mathematica. But I recommend using Latex for typesetting reports and papers and use Mathematica for what it is best at: Computations, analysis and graphics.

Comment: Thanks, @Nasser. I do use LaTeX for most of my docuents. But here I just made a quick physics assignment in Mathematica and I don't have much time to convert it into LaTex. The built in LaTex Save As feature in Mathematica does not do the job properly, unfortunately. You need to fix the figures, references and formatting. :(

Comment: Use *MaTeX* (which you can find online).